# Cannot create an instance of Application ViewModel

Tags: android, android-lifecycle, android-architecture-components, android-viewmodel, application-lifecycle

I'm Trying to make a viewmodel scoped to my application to control logic related to showing of not showing pin in multi activity app .

I've used AndroidViewModel to pass the application to it and here is the class for AppViewModel

```
                          @HiltViewModel
              class AppViewModel @Inject constructor(
                  private val getUserPassCodeUseCase: GetUserPassCodeUseCase,
                  private val isPasscodeInputUseCase: IsPasscodeInputUseCase,
                  private val clearAllDataUseCase: ClearAllDataUseCase,
                  @ApplicationContext private val context: Context
              ) : AndroidViewModel((context as App)) {
              
                  private val _openPin = MutableSharedFlow<Long>()
                  val openPin = _openPin.asSharedFlow()
              
                  // uptime in millis
                  private var time: Long = 0
                  private var restoreStatus = RestoreStatus.EMPTY
                  private var isPasscode = false
                  private var passCode = ""
              
                  init {
              
                     // get user status
              
                  }
                  private fun checkIfShouldLock() {
                      viewModelScope.launch {
              
                          isPasscode = withContext(IO) {
                              isPasscodeInputUseCase()
                          }
              
                          val userHasAccount = (restoreStatus == RestoreStatus.ID_SUBMISSION
                                  || restoreStatus == RestoreStatus.TERMS_AND_CONDITION
                                  || restoreStatus == RestoreStatus.ACTIVATE_CARD
                                  || restoreStatus == RestoreStatus.FULL_NAME
                                  || restoreStatus == RestoreStatus.COMPLETED)
              
                          if (true)
                              _openPin.emit (System.currentTimeMillis() )
                      }
                  }
              
                  fun onResume() {
                      updatePasscode()
                      if (!isPasscode) {
                          time = 0
                          return
                      }
              
                      val now = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()
                      when {
                          time == 0L -> {
                              // remember first value
                              time = now
                          }
                          // check is session expired
                          now - time > sessionExpiredTime -> {
                              time = now
                              when (restoreStatus) {
                                  RestoreStatus.COMPLETED -> checkIfShouldLock()
                                  RestoreStatus.EMPTY -> {}
                                  else -> {}
                              }
                          }
                          else -> {
                              time = now
                          }
                      }
                  }
              
                  fun onPause() {
                      updatePasscode()
                      viewModelScope.launch {
                          delay(Constants.PASSCODE_DELAY)
                          if (!isPasscode) {
                              time = 0
                              return@launch
                          }
                          // start "timer"
                          time = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()
                      }
                  }
              
                  private fun updatePasscode() {
                      viewModelScope.launch {
                          isPasscode = withContext(IO) {
                              isPasscodeInputUseCase()
                          }
                      }
              
                  }
              
                  fun logout() {
                      viewModelScope.launch {
                          withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
                              clearAllDataUseCase()
                          }
                      }
                  }
              
                  companion object {
                      const val MAIN_VIEW_MODEL_TAG = "AppViewModel"
                  }
              }
```

and here is my application class and how i try to access the viewmodel

```
        @HiltAndroidApp
          class App : Application(), Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks, 
         Configuration.Provider {
          
              @Inject
              lateinit var workerFactory: HiltWorkerFactory
          
              override fun getWorkManagerConfiguration() =
                  Configuration.Builder()
                      .setWorkerFactory(workerFactory)
                      .build()
          
              // uptime in millis
              private var time: Long = 0
          
               var appViewModel : AppViewModel ?=null
               var currentActivity : String ?=null
          
              override fun onCreate() {
                  super.onCreate()
                  AndroidThreeTen.init(this)
          
                  appViewModel = ViewModelProvider.AndroidViewModelFactory(this).create(AppViewModel::class.java)
                  appViewModel?.openPin?.onEach {
          
                     // if (authToken.isNotEmpty())
                          when (currentActivity) {
                              SplashActivity::class.java.name,
                              PinActivity::class.java.name -> Unit
                              else -> {
                                  startActivity(Intent(this, PinActivity::class.java).apply {
                                     // flag of should end with result or not
                                      // putExtra(Constants.IS_CAME_FROM_BACKGROUND, true)
                                      flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
                                  })
                              }
          
                      }
                  }
          
          
                  setupCrashlytics()
          
                  if (BuildConfig.DEBUG)
                      Timber.plant(Timber.DebugTree())
                  else
                      Timber.plant(CrashReportingTree())
          
          
                  DyScan.init(this, Constants.DYSCAN_API_KEY)
                  registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(this)
          
              }
          
              private fun setupCrashlytics() {
                  with(FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance()) {
                      setCrashlyticsCollectionEnabled(!BuildConfig.DEBUG)
                  }
              }
          
              private fun isDeviceRooted(): Boolean {
                  var process: Process? = null
                  return try {
                      process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su")
                      true
                  } catch (e: Exception) {
                      Timber.i(e, "Rooted device command exception")
                      false
                  } finally {
                      if (process != null) {
                          try {
                              process.destroy()
                          } catch (e: Exception) {
                              Timber.i(e, "Rooted device command close exception")
                          }
                      }
                  }
              }
          
              private fun hideSystemBars(activity: Activity) {
                  val windowInsetsController =
                      ViewCompat.getWindowInsetsController(activity.window.decorView) ?: return
                  windowInsetsController.systemBarsBehavior =
                      WindowInsetsControllerCompat.BEHAVIOR_SHOW_BARS_BY_SWIPE
                  windowInsetsController.hide(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.navigationBars())
              }
          
              override fun onActivityCreated(activity: Activity, p1: Bundle?) {
                  currentActivity = activity.localClassName
                  if (isDeviceRooted()) {
                      Toast.makeText(
                          activity,
                          getString(R.string.rooted_device_message),
                          Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                      ).show()
                      activity.finishAffinity()
                  }
              }
          
              override fun onActivityStarted(p0: Activity) {
                  appViewModel?.onResume()
          
              }
              override fun onActivityResumed(p0: Activity) {}
              override fun onActivityPaused(p0: Activity) {}
              override fun onActivityStopped(activity:  Activity) {
               appViewModel?.onPause()
              }
              override fun onActivitySaveInstanceState(p0: Activity, p1: Bundle) {}
              override fun onActivityDestroyed(p0: Activity) {}
          
          }
```

i keep getting RuntimeException: Cannot create an instance of class x.x.AppViewModel

```
           2022-03-08 22:29:44.189 10889-10889/com.x.x E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.x.x, PID: 10889
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create application com.x.x.App: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create an instance of class com.x.x.AppViewModel
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6991)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700(ActivityThread.java:274)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2093)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:233)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8010)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:631)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:978)
 Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create an instance of class com.x.x.AppViewModel
    at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$AndroidViewModelFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.kt:230)
    at com.x.x.App.onCreate(App.kt:54)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1208)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6986)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700(ActivityThread.java:274) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2093) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:233) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8010) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:631) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:978) 
 Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.x.x.AppViewModel.<init> [class android.app.Application]
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2332)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:1728)
    at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$AndroidViewModelFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.kt:228)
    at com.x.x.App.onCreate(App.kt:54) 
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1208) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6986) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700(ActivityThread.java:274) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2093) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:233) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8010) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:631) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:978)
```

What i am doing wrong in this implementation ?
Is this the right way to implement a viewModel scoped to application ?

Comment: "I'm Trying to make a viewmodel scoped to my application to control logic related to showing of not showing pin in multi activity app" -- your `Application` lives for the entire lifetime of your process. Hence, an `Application`-scoped `ViewModel` would live for the entire lifetime of your process. So, what is the value of using a Jetpack `ViewModel` here?

Comment: I thought of using viewModel as the easiest way to make network calls in background and handle all logic related to the results , I thought it would be best practice , what approach would you suggest? .

Comment: I do not know what "control logic related to showing of not showing pin in multi activity app" means, so I cannot make recommendations of what to do. However, you appear to be spending a lot of time trying to get a Jetpack `ViewModel` to work here, and it does not appear to be helping you.

Comment: I have in app session of 5 minutes if user left the app in background for more than this time  , i call user status api to check if his server side session is still valid if so i should show him the pin activity to validate him otherwise i should redirect to login

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, something is trying to call a no argument constructor on your ViewModel, but you have only defined a constructor that takes arguments.

Answer (score 0):

You have arguments in viewmodel constructor. You will have to extend viewmodel factory and handle the parameters passed.  Later pass the required parameter values to custom viewmodel factory instance. Finally use the custom view model factory instance in ViewModelProvider.AndroidViewModelFactory(this ,customInstance).create (AppViewModel::class.java)